# Bandpass audio filter in combination with PGA2311 analog ouput pins

Tags: audio, pcb-design, schematics, preamp

I am working on modular preamp and I have Digital&Analog Power Supply, motherboard with CPU and Volume Control daugtherboard. On Volume Control Daughterboard there is an PGA2311 Volume Controller IC from Texas Instruments and my question is. Do I need analog audio bandpass filter on output side of this board and do I need buffer stage on input of this daughterboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need analog audio bandpass filter on output side of this board
>   and do I need buffer stage on input of this daughterboard?

The spec for the PGA2311 says that the preferred analogue signal source impedance into the device is 2kohm or less with 600 ohm as the accepted norm. The analogue inputs are single-ended and this is OK providing that the signal is single ended - if your source is differential then a differential to single ended op-amp stage would be needed.

As for the output you don't need an analogue filter on the output stage for it to perform OK. However, you may want to implement tone controls and this might be construed as an analogue filter within the scope of your question but only you know the answer to this.

Note that the output is specified as being capable of driving 600 ohm circuits

Comment: Ok, I am working on two version of this PCB, one with RCA jacks and the other with XLR jacks. Since RCA jack is used for single ended signals, there is not need for extra components, but, if XLR version is in question, I need to transform differential driving to single ended input, compatible with PGA2311, am I right?

Comment: @MarkoFrelih Yes, for balanced inputs you ideally would use a differential amplifier configuration or maybe an instrumentation amplifier.

Comment: Ok, but is LME48710 opamp from Texas Instruments good choice for this task?

Comment: Figure 85 shows the type of circuit you need but this chip is intended to run from +/-15V rails and doesn't give too much information about how it will perform on lower voltage supplies so I would say there are better devices around than this if you have only +/-5V rails.

Comment: Voltage rail is not a problem, I've got +/-15V rails, I've predicted them and made several voltage rails! Do you have maybe some reference design for balanced to single ended conversion? And for the optional filters, what kind of resistors and capacitors should be used (for audio applications)?

Comment: Figure 85 shows a design for balanced to unbalanced converter. There are plenty of designs on the internet how they work and an answer here is beyond the scope of the question. Same with filters but nobody can tell what you need with some design criteria.

Comment: Ok, will dig in! But, from "real life" experience, what kind of capacitors and resistors (because they have many parameters) are best suited for audio applications?

Comment: @MarkoFrelih ceramic surface mount and metal film surface mount resistors are quite ok. If the filter is critical then the caps should be C0G/NP0 types.

Comment: Should LME49710 pins, marked as NC (Not Connected) should not be connected at all, or they must be connected to analog ground plane?

Comment: Leave them unconnected is always the best policy.

Comment: Ok, just final question. I am reading LME49710 opamp datasheet and I've encountered several THD+N vs. Supply Voltage graphs. Why does this opamp have better THD+N performance (lower value) at higher voltages, because it can be driven also with +/-12V, but it has higher THD+N, which is not as good as at +/-15V?

Comment: Hard to say but it's possibly internal biasing gives out a little below 12v.